# Facebook share dialog (URL Redirection) get response/feedback on redirect uri (redirect_uri)

Tags: facebook, url, redirect, dialog, share

I'm using Facebook's share dialog with URL Redirection as shown here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Everything works fine, but the problem I'm having is that I need to get some kind of response or feedback in the redirect uri to know whether the user has published or cancelled the share.
I thought the `post_id` would be included as query string when redirecting. But this is not the case... I just get a trailing `#_=_`

So... is it possible to get somehow the response or some kind of feedback when redirecting to know whether the user has actually published the post or not?

> Please also note that I cannot use the FB.ui API as the callback is
>   not working at all when using it inside a web mobile view.

Thanks!

Comment: what for do you need the callback/response?

Comment: I need it so I can display different content in the redirected page based on whether they've shared the link or not.

Comment: ok, because that´s not allowed. users must share/like/comment stuff because they really want to, not because they get different or additional content.

Comment: But why is it possible to get this kind of feedback when using FB.ui (callback function), but not when using URL redirection?

Comment: I guess I'll have to use the Feed dialog instead that actually provides the post_id after sharing. I still don't understand why the share dialog doesn't behave in the same way.

Comment: the post_id is only there when you authorize the user with publish_actions. and you will definitely not get that one approved for stuff that is not allowed.